# Microsoft AnalysisServices - start and stop server using Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, azure-functions, azure-analysis-services

I wanted to write an Azure Function to stop and resume MS Analysis Sevice.
I have been tasked to do this using [API Resume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/servers/resume) and [API Suspend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/servers/suspend).
It's my first time with C# (I have Python/Javascript background).
What am I doing wrong? Can someone provide correct solution? Would be grateful from the bottom of my heart.

Here is my current code sample:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    var subscriptionId = "mySId";
    var resourceGroupName = "myRGName";
    var serverName = "mySName";
    var APIurl = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/{serverName}/resume?api-version=2017-08-01";

    var response = await client.PostAsync(APIurl, null);
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

This is what I get in console. Server is not stopping though.
[image]

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* If you receive an exception, please add the exception details. If the response is not expected, share the actual and the expected response.

Comment: updated with console screen. The server is not stopping. All I want to do is to call the REST API to stop the Analysis Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those in times of need - this is my complete working solution.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

namespace ManageAS
{
    public class ManageAS
    {
        string accessToken = null;
        string responseString = null;
        string serverStatus = null;
        string serverFullURI = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FULL_SERVER_URI");
        static string shortServerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SHORT_SERVER_NAME");
        string resourceURI = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
        string clientID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENT_ID");
        string clientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENT_SECRET");
        string tenantID = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TENANT_ID");
        static string resourceGroupName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME");
        static string subscriptionId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SUBSCRIPTION_ID");
        static Uri apiURI = null;

        [FunctionName("PerformAction")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
            ILogger log)
        {    
            await GetAccessToken();
            await GetServerStatus(accessToken);

            if (serverStatus == "Paused")
            {
                apiURI = new Uri(string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/{2}/resume?api-version=2017-08-01", subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, shortServerName));
                this.responseString = await ServerManagement(apiURI, accessToken);
            }

            if (serverStatus == "Succeeded")
            {
                apiURI = new Uri(string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/{2}/suspend?api-version=2017-08-01", subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, shortServerName));
                this.responseString = await ServerManagement(apiURI, accessToken);
            }

            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, responseString);
        }

        protected async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID;
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            var token = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURI, new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret));
            accessToken = token.AccessToken;
            return accessToken;
        }

        protected async Task<string> ServerManagement(Uri url, string token)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url.ToString(), null);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            HttpContent content = response.Content;

            string json;
            json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return json;
        }

        protected async Task<string> GetServerStatus(string token)
        {
            var url = new Uri(string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/providers/Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/{2}?api-version=2017-08-01", subscriptionId, resourceGroupName, shortServerName));

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url.ToString());

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string sJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var dictResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(sJson);
            if (!dictResult.ContainsKey("properties")) return null;
            var dictProperties = dictResult["properties"] as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject;
            if (dictProperties == null || !dictProperties.ContainsKey("state")) return null;
            serverStatus = Convert.ToString(dictProperties["state"]);
            return serverStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the api "Resume" you mentioned in your question requires Azure Active Directory OAuth2 Flow, so you need to get the access token first by referring to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) and then use the access token to request this api in your function code.

In the code of your function app, you need to set the access token which we get above as the value of Authorization and then do the post reuqest.

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
```

Comment: Gonna mark this as an answer but I have additional question. As the docs are not that friendly (as usual with MS) there is something I don't understand. 
Can't I just do something like below?
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(this.resourceURI);

It gives me some sort of token, but still I am unauthorized.

Comment: Hi Razi, I'm afraid we can't get the token by "AzureServiceTokenProvider". Per my understanding, "AzureServiceTokenProvider" can just be used to get the access token from the service on Azure which use MSI, such as app service on Azure get the access token of the key vault.